# Enabling /bin/bash on Catalina - invisible to System Preferences -> Security & Privacy -> Full Disk Access

Tags: macos, security, bash, permission, catalina

I am having trouble enabling /bin/bash on Catalina - Macos 10.15.1

When I try to enable it using "System Preferences -> Security & Privacy -> Full Disk Access", the pop-up finder list doesn't show /bin/bash.

As you can see from this screenshot:

[image]

The permissions on bash seem OK:

> ls -l /bin/bash
>   -r-xr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  623344 Oct 24 02:34 /bin/bash

Comment: OK - I've found a solution... I used 'go to folder' in Finder to find /bin/bash, which I then copied to "System Preferences -> Security & Privacy -> Full Disk Access" - by dragging it with three fingers.... I hope there's an easier solution.

Comment: Can you explain exactly what you're trying to do? Why does bash need 'enabling'? If you're trying to get Full Disk Access, you need to give that to Terminal.app, not bash.

Comment: I'm using bash in a cron job. I found zsh broke (it doesn't have 'tempfile', as a builtin, for example), and bash failed with error 2. Now I've given bash Full Disk Access, my cron job is working perfectly.

Answer (score 6):

I followed Peter Brooks' suggestion and it worked for me:

1. system Preferences -> Security & Privacy -> Privacy -> Full Disk Access
2. Click the lock in the lower left corner to allow changes
3. Separately, Open a finder window
4. Select Go -> Go to Folder... from the menu bar
5. Type /bin and click Go.
6. Drag /bin/bash to the Full Disk Access (right hand side)

Done.

When I Just clicked the + in the Full Disk Access thing, i could not find /bin/bash . It somehow wasn't visible. ¯\*(ツ)*/¯

Answer (score 2):

The screenshot shows the content of `/usr/bin`, not of `/bin` :-)

Comment: Yes, you're absolutely right - thank you! Silly me.. So, now my problem is how to get to /bin - in bash, it's /private/bin - but I can't find /private with finder. I've tried:    chflags nohidden /private -- but get:
chflags: /private: Operation not permitted